# Unable to images in collapsed columns on a mobile device - bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Question Background:**

I have a webpage that features a column with 4 images. Each column is set at `col-lg-3` and `col-sm-12` respectively. I am implementing media queries to resize the images when the site is used on mobile devices.

**The Issue:**

The Images are evenly space when viewed on a PC or on mobile device when held horizontally but when viewed on a device in a portrait style the images are no centering in the divs.

This is the page when viewed on a PC or on a device horizontally:

[image]

This is when viewed on a device held in a portrait fashion:

[image]

**Code:**

This is the HTML markup for the images:

```
<div class="productLogo">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12 text-center" style="padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; width:25%;"><img class="img-responsive" src="~/Images/CamaroWeb.png" /></div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12 text-center" style="padding-top:15px; padding-bottom:15px; width:25%;"><img class="img-responsive" src="~/Images/axminster.png" /></div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12 text-center" style="padding-top:15px; padding-bottom:15px; width:25%;"><img class="img-responsive" src="~/Images/Gerflor.png" /></div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12 text-center" style="padding-top:15px; padding-bottom:15px; width:25%;"><img class="img-responsive" src="~/Images/altro.png" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

productLogo class:

```
.productLogo {
    background-color: #335CAD;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    width:100%;
}
```

**If anyone can advise me on how I get the images to center in the divs on a mobile device that would be great**

Comment: *Each column is set at col-lg-3 and col-sm-12 respectively.* It is vice-versa in your markup :)

Comment: could you please reproduce the issue in a fiddle..

Comment: Try to remove class="img-responsive".

Comment: Look this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/alysonsm/52a5qxL4/

Comment: The problem is with "display: block;" into the class img-responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try switching the `col` classes so you build from a mobile-first perspective.

```
<div class="productLogo">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-3 text-center" style="padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; width:25%;"><img class="img-responsive" src="~/Images/CamaroWeb.png" /></div>
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-3 text-center" style="padding-top:15px; padding-bottom:15px; width:25%;"><img class="img-responsive" src="~/Images/axminster.png" /></div>
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-3 text-center" style="padding-top:15px; padding-bottom:15px; width:25%;"><img class="img-responsive" src="~/Images/Gerflor.png" /></div>
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-3 text-center" style="padding-top:15px; padding-bottom:15px; width:25%;"><img class="img-responsive" src="~/Images/altro.png" /></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alysonsm/52a5qxL4/

The problem is with "display: block;" into the class img-responsive. If you remove it you will be able to center the objects.

Html with removed class "img-reponsive":

```
<img  src="~/Images/CamaroWeb.png" /></div>
```